# How use NSSortdescriptor with a specific name first, then sorted on name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nssortdescriptor

Is it possible to use NSSortDescriptor to sort for a given value first, then sorted after the names of the objects?

```
NSArray *values = @[@"Fish",@"Me", @"Aardvark ", @"Turtle"]
```

Wanted result:

```
NSArray *sortedvalues = @[@"Me", @"Aardvark",@"Fish", @"Turtle"]
```

Comment: Must it be a sort descriptor?  Its easy with a comparator, but sort descriptor requires that the array contains a KVO compliant object.

Comment: Using it with fetched results controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sort descriptor is for when the contained object is KVO compliant (responds to valueForKey:). The way to do it with a comparator is...

```
NSArray *values = @[@"Fish",@"Me", @"Aardvark ", @"Turtle"];

NSComparisonResult (^comparator)(id,id) = ^(id left, id right) {
    if ([left isEqualToString:@"Me"]) return NSOrderedAscending;
    if ([right isEqualToString:@"Me"]) return NSOrderedDescending;
    return [left compare:right];
};
NSArray *sortedValues = [values sortedArrayUsingComparator:comparator];
```

I guess you can add an empty key path and use a sort descriptor (thanks to @Prince), but it seems like an extra step...

```
// define the comparator as above
NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"" ascending:YES comparator:comparator];
NSArray *sorted = [values sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sd]];
```

**EDIT**

Say the elements of the array are really KVO objects.  Then sort descriptor is a more natural fit.  Just apply the idea given above with a key path to the strings, e.g.

```
NSDictionary *kvo0 = @{ @"prop": @"Fish"};
NSDictionary *kvo1 = @{ @"prop": @"Me"};
NSDictionary *kvo2 = @{ @"prop": @"Ardvark"};
NSDictionary *kvo3 = @{ @"prop": @"Turtle"};
NSArray *values = @[kvo0, kvo1, kvo2, kvo3];

NSComparisonResult (^comparator)(id,id) = ^(id left, id right) {
    if ([left isEqualToString:@"Me"]) return NSOrderedAscending;
    if ([right isEqualToString:@"Me"]) return NSOrderedDescending;
    return [left compare:right];
};
NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"prop" ascending:YES comparator:comparator];
NSArray *sorted = [values sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sd]];
```

You'll want to change @"prop" to the key path upon which you want to sort the managed objects.

Comment: Looks like a good solution, i'm using it with fetched results controller, so i don't actually have the result array

Comment: Do you mean the array doesn't really contain strings?

Comment: Yes, its actually objects with name attributes

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sort descriptor with a comparator like this...

```
NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"" ascending:YES comparator:^(NSString *string1, NSString *string2) {
    if ([string1 isEqualToString:@"Me"]){
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    // edited thanks to @danh
    if ([string2 isEqualToString:@"Me"]){
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    return [string1 compare:string2];
}
```

Then use this to sort your array.

If the sort descriptor is not required then just use the comparator to sort the array.

Comment: This was my thought originally, too, but the comparator needs to be ready to see "me" as either the left hand or the right hand operand.